# www-data@localhost using password NO

Tags: mysql

I use plesk 9.3, which is required by Serverloft.
We are hosting on 24 websites on it. First, it said too many connection error, and then when I search the main problem.

The problem is:

```
Warning:  mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/vhosts/mimarki.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs/pages.php on line 23
```

The database user that the application should be using to connect is not named `www-data`, and does have a password.

Also, the MySQL performance is very low indeed.

I guess there is a configuration problem but it's a mystery for now.

Could you please help me about what can it be? How can this problem be solved?

Comment: by the way, I'm running this on Ubuntu Server.

Comment: What's on line 23 of `subdomains/test/httpdocs/pages.php`?  And where are the username and password defined that it's using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can somehow administer the MySQL server, try there command

```
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

Sometimes if there are too many connection errors between your application server and MySQL server, it refuses any further connections from that host.

Answer (score 2):

If your mysql connection is done by www-data instead of an other user, check your configuration. You should define somewhere the MySQL user and password.

The performance issue is maybe linked, or you can check if your DNS working well from MySQL and from your Web server.